# How to modify openweathermap JS to use latitude longitude values

Tags: javascript, html, latitude-longitude, openweathermap, weather

I recently posted another question about the following JS openweathermap weather app i'm re-purposing. This is a follow up question to that.

[https://codepen.io/stack-findover/pen/vYgQrPP](https://stackoverflow.com)

Currently, the code uses city search and geolocation for the getWeather function. I'd like to modify the code to use a specific set of Lat / Long coordinates instead. What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Relevant code blocks below:

```
var weatherData = {};
var api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=&lon=-&units=imperial";
var id = "&APPID=acc38546e41e0baf9aa6ba45661c094b";
var cnt =  "&cnt=4"
var country="";
var ctyName = "";
var options = {
              weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",
              day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
            };
```

```
var curDate = $(".cur-date");
curDate.html(new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options));

$.ajax({url: "https://ipinfo.io/json?"})
.done( function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  country = res.country;
  ctyName = "q="+res.city+","+country;

  getWeather();
});


function getWeather() {
$.ajax({url: api+ctyName+id+cnt, dataType: 'json', success: function(result) {
  $('#loader').hide();
  console.log(result);
  weatherData = result;
  var icons= [];

  $("#loc").html(result.city.name+", "+result.city.country);
  $("#cur-weath").html(result.list[0].weather[0].main);
  $("#cur-deg").html(Math.round((result.list[0].main.temp * (9/5)) - 459.67)+"°");
  $("#cur-desc").html(result.list[0].weather[0].description);
  var icon = result.list[0].weather[0].icon;
  setBackground(icon);
  //icons.push(result.list[0].weather[0].icon+".png");
  console.log(Icons[icon].icn);
  skycons.set("cur-icon",Icons[icon].icn);
 // $("#cur-icon").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+icons[0]+"'style='width:100px;height:100px;'>");
  for(var i=1;i<4;i++) {
    var $next=$(".next-weath");
    icons.push(result.list[i].weather[0].icon);
    var dt = new Date(result.list[i].dt_txt);
    if(dt == "Invalid Date") { //modify dt for internet explorer compatibility
      var ar = result.list[i].dt_txt.split(" ");
      dt = new Date(ar[0]+"T"+ar[1]);
    }
    var hour = dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", hour12: true,  });
    $next.eq(i-1).find(".next-hour").html(hour);
    $next.eq(i-1).find(".next-desc").text(result.list[i].weather[0].description);
    $next.eq(i-1).find(".next-deg").html(Math.round((result.list[i].main.temp * (9/5)) - 459.67)+"°");
    skycons.set($next.eq(i-1).find(".next-icon")[0], Icons[icons[i-1]].icn);
  }


},

error: function(error, errorType, errorMessage) {
    $("#loc").html("Unable to Locate").next().hide();
},

beforeSend: function() {
    $("#loc").html("loading").next().show();

}});
}

$("button").on("click", getCityWeather);

$("input").keydown(function(event){
  if (event.which == 13)
    getCityWeather();
});

$(".next-deg").on("click", function() {
  if(weatherData)
    changeTempScale( $(this));
});

$("#cur-deg").on("click", function() {
  if(weatherData)
    changeTempScale( $(this));
});


function setBackground(icon) {
$(".wrap").css('background-image', 'url(' + Icons[icon].bg + ')');
}

function getCityWeather() {
$("input").val()
ctyName = "q="+$("input").val();
getWeather();
}
```

Ive attempted to override the functions by modifying the openweathermap api link, as in the following.. but this did not give the expected result.

```
var weatherData = {};
var api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=&lon=&units=imperial";
```

Answer (score 0):

The api variable currently contains `lat=&lon=`. Try removing that from the api variable. Then remove your variables for `country` and `ctyName`. Finally, create new variables for `lat` and `lon` to build the request URL and see if that works for you.

The resulting request URL should look something like:

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?units=imperial&APPID=acc38546e41e0baf9aa6ba45661c094b&cnt=4&lat=43&lon=-70.2

Comment: That did the trick, appreciate your help!